# A simple example on the custom layer API (TensorRT 2.1)?

Tags: c++, deep-learning, nvidia, tensorrt

I am using `TensorRT 2.1` and want to implement a simple custom layer. (The goal is to run `Single Shot Detector` using `TensorRT` on an embedding system.)

To practice, I wanted to make an `Inc` layer (just adding 1.0 to an input tensor values and keeping dimension the same).

I implement `Inc` class following the `class Reshape : public Iplugin` in `sampleFasterRNN.cpp` example. I kept everything almost the same except `getOutputDimensions()` to keep the same dimension. (this seems fine.)

**Where should I implement the "adding 1.0" part?** I guess it should be in "enqueue()". So, I tried

```
int enqueue(int batchSize, const void*const *inputs, void** outputs, void*, cudaStream_t stream) override
{
  # the below is from the Reshape class. seems to copy from input to output
  CHECK(cudaMemcpyAsync(outputs[0], inputs[0], mCopySize * batchSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice, stream));
  # add 1.0 to first ten values
  float* foutputs = (float*) outputs[0];
  int i; for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) foutputs[i] += 1.0;   
  return 0;
}
```

However, this part results in "segmentation fault" error.

My questions are:

1. Where and how can I implement some calculation between input and output?
2. Can anyone provide a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the file `samples/samplePlugin/samplePlugin.cpp` and look at the `FCPlugin` class. Your actual computation should go into the `enqueue` method. You might have to write a CUDA kernel that does the increment.